# RecyclerView DynamicAdapter - List grouped by

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to have a `DynamicAdapter` that contains a List of persons from database grouped by nationality.

My code is:

```
List<Person> listOfPersons = database.personDao().selectAllPersons();

Map<String,List<Person>> personsGroupedByNationality =
listOfPersons.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person:getNationality));
```

I want to have a dynamic Adapter for every nationality we have where :

- footer: value of nationality
- items: List of persons that have this
  nationality

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: i think you will use map data structure for organize your lists then you well depend on recyclerView viewType to decide which item will be inflated. you should make a quick search for sticky header recycler view or sectioned recycler
 view. 
also take a look on ExpendableListView and ExpendableRecyclerView. @Vaniokmd

Comment: Try this https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders